# re-render vs visibility hidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component of conditional rendering.

And I can make 2 ways for this.

```
function SimpleComponent({ visible }){
  return (
    <button style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
      {visible && <p>Visible!</p>}
      <p style={{ visibility: `${visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>Visible!</p>
    </button>
  );
}
```

But I am not sure which is a better way for efficiency.

Please give me an idea or opinion about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your needs. If you want to **hide** the element, but **do not** remove it from the *DOM* tree (so you can have access to it - apply some animations, pop it out smoothly, measure element height/width etc), use css `visibility` property.

If you just want to hide it and you don't want to access it while it's hidden, use condition `visible && ...`. That element won't be rendered in the *DOM* tree at all.

**Note**: In matter of efficiency - the second approach is better since the less elements in the *DOM* tree, the better.

Note also that even if element has applied `visibility: hidden` property, it still takes space in your app (in the viewport) and can affect other elements position.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to this stupid question. :) I thought the second way better but I just was not sure...

Comment: That's why I added `position: absolute` on the parent element.